# Webpack Module Federation Shared Dependencies

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I have this example from the github repo [Dashboard](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/dashboard-example). I cant understand what the shared optoin does exactly. It seems that even if i disable the shared option in the federation plugin the dependencies from each app will still be downloaded.

This is the network in both apps with the shared option off.

**http://localhost:3001/**

[image]

**http://localhost:3002/**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably shared dependencies aren't correctly set up in this example. The value of `sharedReduce` in *app2/webpack.config.js* is

```
{ "react-16.14.0": "react", "react-dom-16.14.0": "react-dom" }
```

instead of

```
{ "react": "^16.14.0", "react-dom": "^16.14.0" }
```

With this configuration, the page will load shared dependencies once.

Updating the value of sharedReduce using the code below will solve the issue

```js
const sharedReduce = ['react', 'react-dom'].reduce((shared, pkg) => {
  Object.assign(shared, { [pkg]]: '^${require(pkg).version}' });
  return shared;
}, {});
```

**Side notes**: at the time of writing, *app2* won't run without removing the `library` property in `ModuleFederationPlugin` configuration